# C# does the name of a variable in a block affects memory?

Tags: c#, exception, out-of-memory

I have noticed that when I run this code:

```
{
    int[] a = new int[int.MaxValue / 8];
}
{
    int[] a = new int[int.MaxValue / 8];
}
```

I get OutOfMemoryException. But if I do this:

```
{
    int[] a = new int[int.MaxValue / 16];
}
{
    int[] a = new int[int.MaxValue / 16];
}
{
    int[] a = new int[int.MaxValue / 16];
}
{
    int[] a = new int[int.MaxValue / 16];
}
```

there's no Exception. But then when I change the name of 2 variables:

```
{
    int[] a = new int[int.MaxValue / 16];
}
{
    int[] a = new int[int.MaxValue / 16];
}
{
    int[] b = new int[int.MaxValue / 16];
}
{
    int[] b = new int[int.MaxValue / 16];
}
```

I get OutOfMemoryException again.

Why in the first and last times there was OutOfMemoryException but not in the second one which used the same amount of space?

Edit:
I understand that the first OutOfMemoryException is different because the memory needs to be contiguous but not why there was no OutOfMemoryException in the second one but there was on the third

Comment: names make no difference. ITs just that you are probably on the edge of memory space and sometimes wobble over it and other times not.

Comment: @pm100 No. I tried this something like 10 times and every time got the same result

Comment: ok, look at the IL , see how different in the 2 cases

Comment: My **guess** is the compiler, jitter, or garbage collector sees the names as a _hint_ that when you declare a new `a` you really are done with the previous `a`, such that in the former case where the name of the variable in each block is the same the garbage collector cleans up the memory from the previous block each time, but in the latter case that memory from 2nd block hasn't gone away yet when it tries to get memory for the third.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I'd wondered if it might be some quirk of how the locals are allocated during JIT, e.g., maybe the same local slot gets reused in his second snippet but not the third.  According to [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/), however, both the IL and assembly are identical for the second and third snippets, in both release and debug mode.  Maybe OP is running with an older compiler/JIT, though.

Comment: Are you running it in release or debug configuration? And is debugger attached?

Comment: @Evk on debug configuration and the debugger isn't attached

Answer (score 0):

Variable names do not affect memory, the compiler doesn't actually save the original variable names.

Comment: It depends on what mode you compile in, and what the scope of the variables are if the compiler preserves them or mangles them. For example public variables (fields) are name-preserved. Local fields may be mangled in release mode but remain intact in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

That is a good question, I am not sure I am the best to answer but I'll give it a shot.

An array requires that the memory is contiguous, meaning it has to be all next to each other.  So when you ask for 2 arrays of int.max / 8 or roughly 500 million integers you are saying I need 2 500 million blocks of memory next to each other, not just 1 billion blocks of memory.  When you then ask for 4 250 million blocks this is the same thing, you are asking still for 1 billion blocks of memory but in 4 250 blocks.  As for why the third one failed...this might have just been bad luck or the garbage collector is just slow...not really sure.  It should free up that memory once you leave the block so naming it different shouldn't really matter, although maybe giving it the same variable name forces a collection...I am not an expert on garbage collection.

Comment: Actually thinking about it, my guess is the third fails only because you first run the second.  I would delete the second and try it again, garbage collector is probably just behind.  You could force collection first just to be sure.